# Why did this question get so many downvotes?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, votes

[How to automatically execute a command every time a certain command terminates?](https://askubuntu.com/q/702325/146980)

What did I do wrong? It's a perfectly suitable question... so why has it got so many downvotes?

Was it due to me not being clear in the first place?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701477/create-a-file-and-write-to-it-using-a-python-script-without-using-the-open-fu) question also got quite a few donwvotes, and I don't understand why...

Since it's likely that those who downvoted it are regulars in the AU community, could you tell me why you downvoted it, so that I can improve in the future?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with last time, people didn't understand what you need. There are super-simple solutions available but you're adamant they're not good enough, but don't explain why.

You did give an example this time (which is a distinct improvement) but then you started saying things like...

> I don't want to run a script that executes two commands...

## Why not?

It's that sort of stuff that confuses people. It makes the problem seem artificial if there's no reason. People often don't like wasting their time; they'd rather help somebody with an actual problem.

So in the future, try not to be too particular. If you have a problem, explain what it is and how you think you'd like to fix it. If you're going to be particular (eg, not using `open()` in Python), you'll have to provide a reason.

Answer (score 4):

Good questions are based on research on the subject of the question. Once that is done, you have at least a clear *assumption* on the options you have, and you can ask *specific* question(s) to achieve your goal and exactly find out were your assumptions may be incorrect. Your question then is based on clear information, either correct or not, and an answer can be given accordingly.

You are doing it exactly the opposite way. You start with a vague idea of what you *think* you want to achieve. However, since you have not put any effort in what are technically the options (at least that's how it seems), you are not able to draw a clear picture at all.

As a result, and I think that is the worst, you are asking us to join you in your attempt to create weird solutions (just come to the idea of opening a file without `open()` or `with open()` in python), based on obviously incorrect assumptions. 
While doing so, you ignore new information people offer you, and you stick to your own incorrect assumptions, constantly give us contradictory information, [like here](https://askubuntu.com/q/702528/72216), in the question: "I don't want a script", in a comment: "a script doesn't matter".

Finally, reposting the question "*so other users will notice*", completes the impression of a messy way of asking questions